# How do virtual functions behave with hidden properties?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-10.0

I have an abstract class that contains a protected property. This property is never initialized but is being hidden inside the derived classes. The abstract class also contains a virtual function that is supposed to access mentioned property and compare it to the method's argument. However the function is called via reflection from the static overload. Something like:

```
class baseClass
{
    private static bool CanProcessRequest(Type type, string segment)
    {
        return ((baseClass?)Activator.CreateInstance(type, true))?.CanProcessRequest(segment) ?? false; ;
    }

    protected virtual bool CanProcessRequest(string segment)
    {
        return this._segment == segment;
    }

    protected string _segment;

    protected baseClass()
    {
    }
}

class derivedClass : baseClass
{
    new string _segment = "Admin/";

    public derivedClass() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

My issue is that the virtual function uses base class' unitialized property instead of derived class' as was intended

My original idea was to assign the property inside the constructor, but it is supposed to be constant and I cannot really modify the constructor arguments. I also tried to maybe cast to the derived class but I failed. Is it possible to force it to use the derived class' property without overloading the function?

Comment: @DA This post is about hiding method which I do not do. I intentionally call the base class function to do operations on the derived class variables

Comment: new string _segment  is hiding the base class _segment so the base class will use _segment from the base and not from your derived class

Comment: @DA Is there a way to bypass this behavior without overloading the virtual function?

Comment: Define in the base the "_segment" like this: protected virtual string _segment { get; set; } and in the derivedClass  define it like:  protected override string _segment { get; set; } = "Admin/";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_segment` is not a property, it is a field.

For this to work as you intend, you could replace that field with an overridable property:

```
protected virtual string _segment { get; set; }
```

Then in your derived class:

```
protected override string _segment { get; set; } = "Admin/";
```

---

If you want to retain `_segment` as a field, you could always set this via the constructor:

```
class baseClass
{
    protected string _segment;
    protected baseClass(string segment)
    {
        _segment = segment;
    }
}

class derivedClass : baseClass
{
    public derivedClass() : base("Admin/")
    { }
}
```

Or to keep `_segment` as optional during construction:

```
class baseClass
{
    protected string _segment;
    protected baseClass()
    { }
}

class derivedClass : baseClass
{
    public derivedClass() : base()
    {
        _segment = "Admin/";
    }
}
```